# Return an array of weekdays in a whole year

Tags: javascript

I want to change code below to return one array of a whole year, while also taking leapyears into account.

This is my solution but it does not take leap years into account and i know there is a prettier way....

The goal is to get an array with only weekdays.

```
function getDaysArray(year, month) {
    var numDaysInMonth, daysInWeek, daysIndex, index, i, l, daysArray;

    numDaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    daysInWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    daysIndex = { 'Sun': 0, 'Mon': 1, 'Tue': 2, 'Wed': 3, 'Thu': 4, 'Fri': 5, 'Sat': 6 };
    index = daysIndex[(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).toString().split(' ')[0]];
    daysArray = [];

    for (i = 0, l = numDaysInMonth[month - 1]; i < l; i++) {
        daysArray.push((i + 1) + '. ' + daysInWeek[index++]);
        if (index == 7) index = 0;
    }

    return daysArray;
}

var year = 2024;
var arrays = [
  getDaysArray(year,1),
  getDaysArray(year,2),
  getDaysArray(year,3),
  getDaysArray(year,4),
  getDaysArray(year,5),
  getDaysArray(year,6),
  getDaysArray(year,7),
  getDaysArray(year,8),
  getDaysArray(year,9),
  getDaysArray(year,10),
  getDaysArray(year,11),
  getDaysArray(year,12)];
var weekdays = [].concat.apply([], arrays);
```

Comment: The [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) already knows how to do that, including leap years. Just start from Jan 1, and incrementally add one to the day-of-month. The `getDay()` method gets you the day-of-week, and `.getMonth()` will tell you when you're in a new month.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, would you have a small hit to push in the right direction? Im basically at a beginner level :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution (as understood to your question). Remove outside of function and put these codes

```
var year = 2024;
var arrays = [];

for(var i=1; i<=12; i++) {
  arrays.push(getDaysArray(year, i));
}


console.log(arrays);
```

Comment: Thanks! The goal is to get one array with the correct named weekdays for the whole year.. i get the same result as i had with this code. It is prettier tho! :)